# Add class to the div if div have specific class

Tags: javascript, jquery, addclass

Here i am trying to add class `alignright` in `blog-post` div if  div have the specific class `blog-post` but bellow code is not working help me to sort out this.

```
<div class="switches">
    <span class="blog off">Blog</span>
</div>
<div class="timeline">
    <script>
    $(".switches span").click(function(){
        $(this).closest("span").toggleClass('off');
        if ( $( this ).hasClass( "blog off" ) ) {
            $('.timeline').first().removeClass('timeline').  
            children('div').hasClass('blog-post').addClass('alignright');            
        }
    });
    </script>
    <div class="single-post single-post blog-post"> 
        <div class="single-post single-post web-post"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: your code looks messed up.

Comment: is that a typo? your code doesnt have script tags, jquery ref etc..

Comment: That's not the right place to add jQuery code.

Comment: where is `timeline` element in your html?

Comment: `hasClass` doesn't accept space separated multiple classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.hasClass()` function doesn't do what your code thinks it does. It always just returns a boolean. You want `.filter()`:

```
 $('.timeline').first().removeClass('timeline').children('div').filter('.blog-post').addClass('alignright');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <div class="switches">
       <span class="blog off">Blog</span>
    </div>
    <div class="timeline">
         <div class="single-post single-post blog-post"></div>
         <div class="single-post single-post web-post"></div>             
    </div>



   <script>
        $(".switches span").click(function(){
            $(this).toggleClass('off');

            if ($(this).hasClass("blog off")) {
                var mydiv = $(this).parent().next();
                mydiv.removeClass('timeline');
                mydiv.find('div.blog-post').addClass('alignright');

            }
        });
   </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the hasClass() method, which will return a boolean value, so calling `addClass` after that it will fail

```
$(".switches span").click(function () {
    //this is the span
    $(this).toggleClass('off');
    if ($(this).hasClass("off")) {
        $(this).next('div.blog-post').addClass('alignright');
    }
});
```